# After some minutes oracle database is down, but listener still active

Tags: linux, fedora, oracle, rdbms

I installed Oracle 12c R2 on my fedora 24 server. Before its updates and the last upgrade to fedora 26 it was running ok, but then neither the listener nor the database can be bringed up. After some research i found a very usefull script called Atlas, designed for fresh system instalation on fedora 26. So i reinstalled Oracle with atlas script help and for some time it was working ok again, but since some days ago the listener works correctly but database don't. When i start the database with lsnrctl start command it starts ok, but after some minutes the database is down.

Reading the alert log i found a line that says "service_died" and googling the error number i found many pages with no reason why the database is down after some random minutes. If for some one the log is a clue here it is

```
<msg time='2018-02-06T13:36:17.187-06:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='machine.domain.org'
 host_addr='x.x.x.x'>
 <txt>06-FEB-2018 13:36:17 * service_update * orcl * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2018-02-06T13:46:17.779-06:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='machine.domain.org'
 host_addr='x.x.x.x'>
 <txt>06-FEB-2018 13:46:17 * service_update * orcl * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2018-02-06T13:56:02.066-06:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='machine.domain.org'
 host_addr='x.x.x.x'>
 <txt>No longer listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=machine.domain.org)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/.../xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2018-02-06T13:56:02.066-06:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='machine.domain.org'
 host_addr='x.x.x.x'>
 <txt>06-FEB-2018 13:56:02 * service_died * orcl * 12537
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2018-02-06T13:56:09.110-06:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='machine.domain.org'
 host_addr='x.x.x.x'>
 <txt>Dynamic address is already listened on (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=machine.domain.org)(PORT=1521)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2018-02-06T13:56:09.110-06:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='machine.domain.org'
 host_addr='x.x.x.x'>
 <txt>06-FEB-2018 13:56:09 * service_register * orcl * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2018-02-06T13:56:12.113-06:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='machine.domain.org'
 host_addr='x.x.x.x'>
 <txt>06-FEB-2018 13:56:12 * service_update * orcl * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
```

I would like to know if there is some recurring process or something that checks oracle configuration or anything, and if it sees something wrong it makes that the database shut down, or if this has happened to some one that can share a solution to this issue.